# Linux postfix/dovecot 554 Relay access denied

Tags: linux, smtp, postfix-mta, mail-server, dovecot

I have this error `554 Relay access denied`  when trying to send email from my outlook client.

I can read incoming mails but cannot send.

If i connect with telnet localhost 25 i can send external emails, but with outlook client it doesn't work.

Here's my postfix and dovecot config :

**postconf -n**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

**doveconf -n**

```
# 2.1.7: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.9.3-x86_64-linode33 x86_64 Ubuntu 13.04 ext3
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: where is your 'outlook client' connecting from? Are you using authentication? You're only having localhost in `mynetworks`, you may want to add the network computers should be allowed to send mails from there.

Comment: it's at my home computer. Yes i use ssl. mynetwork ? So i should add my home computer inet ip ??

Comment: no, I dont't mean ssl (encryption) but authentication (have you set up outlook to authenticate your user when sending messages over smtp via postfix?). `mynetwork` allows relay access without authentication from local networks, if your server is somewhere on the internet then you should better use smtp_auth.

Comment: @mata Ok i had not set smtp authentification in outlook. But i still have the error with authenticate. So i should add something with smtp_auth in the postfix config ?

Comment: no, that's the sasl part - read http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_sasl_authz_relay for more information about how relay access using authentication works (also, the reset of the document explains how to set up sasl).

Comment: ok but if you watch my config file you'll see i already have that

Comment: yea, but depending on your postfix version, you should add the `smtpd_relay_restrictions` option mentioned.

Comment: I ran `postconf -a` and it seems i have not postfix compiled with support for Dovecot SASL. The command shows `cyrus, dovecot` Is it good ?

Comment: @mata hey i added `smtpd_relay_restrictions` with same parameters as `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and it works! I just saw that `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` was to allow only email to be sent locally! Thanks a lot. You could add answer and i would accept it if you wish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a postfix version newer then 2.10, then you need to add the `smtpd_relay_restrictions` option as described [here](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_sasl_authz_relay):

> ```
> # With Postfix 2.10 and later, the mail relay policy is
> # preferably specified under smtpd_relay_restrictions.
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     smtpd_relay_restrictions =
>     permit_mynetworks
>     permit_sasl_authenticated
>     reject_unauth_destination
>
> # Older configurations combine relay control and spam control under
> # smtpd_recipient_restrictions. To use this example with Postfix ≥
> # 2.10 specify "smtpd_relay_restrictions=".
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
>     permit_mynetworks
>     permit_sasl_authenticated
>     reject_unauth_destination
>         ...other rules...
> ```

After that, any sasl authenticated user should be able to send mails through the server using smtp.

Answer (score 0):

For my postfix 2.6.6 on Amazon AWS EC2, it turned out that i had wrong configuration of "mydestination" and "relay_domains" settings in main.cf.
Correct values (ones which worked for me), were:

`mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost
relay_domains = $mydestination`

Comment: my domain name is `necktwi.com`. I have renamed server to `ec2` so myhostname= `ec2.necktwi.com` and mydomain = `necktwi.com`. yet I get the same error